# NPE in BufferedImage on a second image upload try

Tags: java, servlets, bufferedimage

I'm uploading an image to a servlet through an ajax post request (provided by a complex html5 drag and drop plugin's javascript code..which i won't show now)

In a first image upload everything is fine (i'm also sending some data within the ajax post for cropping the image in the server-side and this is the reason for which i had to convert the `InputStream`
gotten from the uploaded image to a `BufferedImage` (the conversion as following :

```
BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(fi.getContent());
```

This is the whole FileUploadServlet servlet :

```
package com.hmkcode;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.hmkcode.vo.FileMeta;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;


//this to be used with Java Servlet 3.0 API
@MultipartConfig 
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // this will store uploaded files
    private static List<FileMeta> files = new LinkedList<FileMeta>();
    /***************************************************
     * URL: /upload
     * doPost(): upload the files and other parameters
     ****************************************************/

    private BufferedImage cropImage(BufferedImage src, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
          BufferedImage dest = src.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
          return dest; 
       }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{

        // 1. Upload File Using Java Servlet API
        //files.addAll(MultipartRequestHandler.uploadByJavaServletAPI(request));            


        HttpServletRequest rq = request;


        // 1. Upload File Using Apache FileUpload
        files.addAll(MultipartRequestHandler.uploadByApacheFileUpload(rq));

        // Remove some files
        while(files.size() > 20)
        {
            files.remove(0);
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////
        System.out.println("Begin:::mytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytests");

        if(files.size()==0)
            System.out.println("files is empty !");
        else        
        for(FileMeta fi : files){
        System.out.println("------->>>>  file name : "+fi.getFileName());
        System.out.println("------->>>>  file size : "+fi.getFileSize());
        System.out.println("------->>>>  file type : "+fi.getFileType());
        System.out.println("------->>>>  file Class : "+fi.getClass());
        System.out.println("------->>>>  file Content : "+fi.getContent());
        System.out.println("______________________________________________");


        ///////////////// /////////////////////////////// /////////////////////////

        // java cropping test :

        BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(fi.getContent());


        File outputfile = new File("C:\\uploadedimgs\\"+UUID.randomUUID()+".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(cropImage(imBuff,
//                                     0,0,200,200
                                       Integer.parseInt(MultipartRequestHandler.cropx1),
                                       Integer.parseInt(MultipartRequestHandler.cropy1),
                                       Integer.parseInt(MultipartRequestHandler.cropw),
                                       Integer.parseInt(MultipartRequestHandler.croph)
                               ), "jpg", outputfile);

        ////////////////////////////////


        }
        System.out.println("fin:::mytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytestsmytests");









        // 2. Set response type to json
        response.setContentType("application/json");

        // 3. Convert List<FileMeta> into JSON format
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // 4. Send resutl to client
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), files);

    }
    /***************************************************
     * URL: /upload?f=value
     * doGet(): get file of index "f" from List<FileMeta> as an attachment
     ****************************************************/
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{

         // 1. Get f from URL upload?f="?"
         String value = request.getParameter("f");

         // 2. Get the file of index "f" from the list "files"
         FileMeta getFile = files.get(Integer.parseInt(value));

         try {      
                // 3. Set the response content type = file content type 
                response.setContentType(getFile.getFileType());

                // 4. Set header Content-disposition
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+getFile.getFileName()+"\"");

                // 5. Copy file inputstream to response outputstream
                InputStream input = getFile.getContent();
                OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*10];

                for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                output.close();
                input.close();
         }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
}
```

Now the problem, which is a NPE, happens in a second upload try.It is the BufferedImage imBuff which is null. this is the exception log :

```
10:10:40,818 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/gencarservces-web].[upload]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet upload a généré une exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hmkcode.FileUploadServlet.cropImage(FileUploadServlet.java:40) [classes:]
    at com.hmkcode.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:95) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
```

Comment: What format do you send to the server from Ajax? Does it differ between the first and the second time? `ImageIO.read()` will return `null` for formats it does not recognize.

Comment: this happened even when i sent the same image twice and the one i've tried was a JPEG.

Comment: How do you know what image you are actually processing? The `files` list, the removal of anything above 20 and then iterating from the front seems a little odd at least, without some further explanation. Do you upload 20 images at a time?